# How to enable "play next" button in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

My friend has a "Play Next" button in YouTube which can be used to queue videos on YouTube without making a separate playlist. I also found an [answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-YouTube-have-play-next-button) on Quora stating that the person has it. It looks something like this:

[image]

My friend has no separate widgets/extensions installed in his browser. I tried looking for, but couldn't find any documentation for the feature.

How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Press the same three dots in the image you have next to the video but here is what pops up...

[image]

(Add to queue, Save to Watch later, Save to playlist, Not interested, and Report)

What you need to press is "Add to queue" and it is like play next